# incorrect response from http request using spring/tomcat

Tags: java, spring, http, tomcat, request

I've got a situation where I am receiving incorrect answers from simple http requests.

On remote tomcat server A I have:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/test/dosomething", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String doSomething() {
    RestTemplate rt = new RestTemplate();
    ResponseEntity<String> rpe = 
    rt.getForEntity("http://foo.dns/test/getstring", String.class);
    return "redirect:" + rpe.getBody();
}
```

This method calls /test/getstring which is on remote tomcat server B.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/test/getstring", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public String getString() {
    return "http:///test.dns";
}
```

When this runs the result of rpe.getBody() on remote server A is '{}http://test.d'. This ofcourse is wrong and does not work.

This is code that:

- When run on remote websphere server A and B has a correct result (http://test.dns)
- When running A and B locally using intellij/tomcat has a correct result
- When running A local and B remote has a correct result
- When running A remote and B local has a correct result
- When executing a curl from Remote A to remote B has a correct result

Any ideas what could cause this behaviour?

I also tried rewriting the resttemplate part using apache httpClient, but this has the same result.

Server A has tomcat 7.0.69 and java 8
Server B has tomcat 7.0.69 and java 7
Both local and remote

Answer (score 0):

You are using @ResponseBody on server b, so it is returning the response as a json

Comment: Ok, but why does it work locally and in all other mentioned cases? Also when not using responseBody but using return type ResponseEntity<String> it also fails

Comment: Can't imagine why it would work, but am guessing here, somehow it drop the "{}" as it is not exist.

Answer (score 0):

I eventually found the cause for this behaviour. We were using a framework that would write data to the response behind the scenes. We were not aware of this behaviour and were treating the controller methods as usual (using a responsebodyband a return type). The framework didn’t require controller methods to return. Because of this 2 responses were written to the response.
Conclusion: I hate frameworks that do things on their own in a non transparant way.
(The framework is an in-house developed framework that the company somehow aquired)